# Module 3G/4G USB for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: pi-3, usb, internet, gsm, modem

I want 3G/4G dongle to connect it via USB to my Raspberry Pi because I want Internet when there is no WiFi to send same scanned data.

Any suggestions (Works in France) ?

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the section on the elinux page [here](https://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_3G_Dongles) for the list of 3G/4G adapters which other people have tested with the Pi.

I think most of the 3G/4G SIM cards would work with the adapters mentioned there, you can check with your carrier and make sure that the adapter you choose does support those frequency bands.